# can grub be installed as first program on new machine?

Tags: partition, grub, gparted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install grub on a completely empty hard drive?](https://serverfault.com/questions/96244/how-to-install-grub-on-a-completely-empty-hard-drive)

I've got a new os setup in virtualbox. I booted into it with gparted live cd. how can I install  grub on the mbr from this point? All the documentation I can find seems to assume you already have a linux installation installed. At the moment my partition layound is /dev/sda and with a partition table created with gparted live to msdos

Comment: Yes, it can be installed in the MBR.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you have *installed an OS*, then either

- A. you already have a bootloader installed and/or configured, or
- B. you need to boot using a live/recovery-CD in order to use this OS.

If you do not have a bootable OS (why not?), then you need to install a bootloader.